# How do I convert a JSON string to a JSON object?

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, listview

I have problem with converting json string to Json Object

I Receive this Json Result from my server :

```
{"type":"news","items":[{"id": "867","title": "مخيّم_بساط_الرّيح - مخيّم_كان_ياما_كان","content": " في المركز الجماهيري ابوسنان ..  اليوم الخامس على التوالي .. ","fromDate": false,"toDate": false,"image": "productImages2/105/2017/07/13/image1499940076.jpg","imageAlt": "مخيّم_بساط_الرّيح - مخيّم_كان_ياما_كان","exLink":"http://www.mas.org.il/page.php?type=page&id=2477&ht=#navbar","price": false}]}
```

and I want to put the result into list view

I have tried many methods which eventually failed

Comment: In what language, platform?

Comment: am working on android application

Comment: Always use tags that indicate what platform language you're using so people that look for specific language/platform will look at your question.

Comment: Have I seen GSON?

Comment: any one can help me ?

Comment: You have to use GSON library to convert json string to JsonObject

Answer (score 0):

simply you can take that received string as string and then convert it

```
String json ={"type":"news","items":[{"id": "867","title": "مخيّم_بساط_الرّيح - مخيّم_كان_ياما_كان","content": " في المركز الجماهيري ابوسنان ..  اليوم الخامس على التوالي .. ","fromDate": false,"toDate": false,"image": "productImages2/105/2017/07/13/image1499940076.jpg","imageAlt": "مخيّم_بساط_الرّيح - مخيّم_كان_ياما_كان","exLink":"http://www.mas.org.il/page.php?type=page&id=2477&ht=#navbar","price": false}]}
```

and now convert in json object

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
```

now you can use it as jsonobject

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
JSONArray jsonArry = jsonObj.getJSONArray("items");
JSONObject jsonObj1 = jsonArry.getJSONObject(0);
String id = jsonObj1.getString("id");
String title= jsonObj1.getString("title");
..
..
..
String price = jsonObj1.getString("price");
```

Comment: thanks for help , put I get this message when try this code : cannot be converted to JSONObject